# Pacimonie and Tor Browser Bundle in Debian

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, debian

When using Tor in Debian Wheezy for multiple applications, what is the preferred setup?
I have installed Parcimonie (https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/parcimonie) so GPG gets key updates through Tor. This installed the Debian Tor package as a dependency. However, for web browsing I want to use the Tor Browser downloaded from the official website as recommended by the Tor Project. Since the Tor Browser ships its own Tor binary, will this mean I have two Tor binaries/processes running when I launch the Tor Browser, and if so, will this create any problems, e.g. how will Parcimonie and/or the Tor Browser know which process to pick? I suppose the versions of Tor may even be different. Should I be adding the Tor Project's own package repository or will this further mess things up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

after looking at the sources, it looks like parcimonie uses torsocks - if that is also installed by your package manager, then it's safe to assume it'll just use the system tor daemon (most likely listening on port 9050) - there's probably a configuration file in /etc/tor/ or /etc/

there shouldn't be any complications whatsoever to have multiple tor processes. (the tor process in tor browser listens on port 9150)

side note, while looking for sources, I found https://github.com/EtiennePerot/parcimonie.sh which claims to have the interesting property of making sure there's different circuits used for requesting keys.

Comment: for what it's worth, I just updated it for torsocks 2.0 compatibility - see https://github.com/mroq/parcimonie.sh